# Count of all queries since MySQL server has started

Tags: mysql

How do you find out how many queries have been executed since the MySQL server has started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysqladmin proc stat
```

This should give you a Questions count (among other information), which is the number of queries asked of the server.

One handy part of the info returned is slow queries count.  Hopefully that is 0. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do it in a query, instead of by running an external program:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Questions';
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 5.1.31 or later, you can do `show status` and check out the row with the name "Queries"

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Queries

If you don't have 5.1, use the "Questions" row.  In 5.1, it won't include queries inside saved procedures.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Questions

Answer (score 0):

Just 
mysqladmin status -p

should give you the useful information and specific information.